# search only for 1st level tr's

Tags: jquery, jquery-selectors

I have a table inside a table. And I want to 'select' only tr from **the first table** using jQuery. How can I do that?

`alert($('#mytable tr').length);` gives me all tr's ....

Sample code is [on jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/radek/cdsCr/2/)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Us the `>` child selector on #mytable's `tbody`:

```
$('#mytable > tbody > tr')
```

Answer (score 1):

```
$('#mytable > tbody > tr:first')
```

Comment: Oh, you changed your question. Initially you asked for only the first tr, but if you want all of them drop the `:first`

Comment: No I'm very certain you changed your question.

Comment: :-) I did edited my question twice. But I didn't change it. To support that I can say that @Jon answered few minutes before you and the answer was correct.